# Add custom field to product settings shipping tab and display value on additional information tab in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to add a "Quantity per package" field to WooCommerce product, and I'd need this field in the Shipping tab of the product backend. Then I need to display this number under the package dimensions in the Additional Informations tab.

I could add a row to the Additional Informations tab, but I don't know how to input the value and make it get that value to display.

Currently I am using the following, someone who can help me on my way?

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'custom_product_additional_information', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_additional_information( $product_attributes, $product ) {
    $product_attributes[ 'attribute_' . 'custom-one' ] = array(
        'label' => __('Quantity per Package'),
        'value' => __('Value 1'),
    );
    return $product_attributes;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code contains:

- Add custom field to product shipping tab
- Save custom field
- Display value on additional Informations tab if NOT empty
- Explanation via comment tags added in the code

```php
// Add custom field to product shipping tab
function action_woocommerce_product_options_shipping(){ 
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'My label', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __( 'My placeholder', 'woocommerce' ),
        'id' => '_quantity_per_package',
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'description' => __( 'My description', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_shipping', 'action_woocommerce_product_options_shipping', 10, 0 );

// Save
function action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object( $product ) {
    // Isset
    if( isset($_POST['_quantity_per_package']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_quantity_per_package', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_quantity_per_package'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 10, 1 );

// Display value on additional Informations tab if NOT empty
function filter_woocommerce_display_product_attributes( $product_attributes, $product ) {
    // Get meta
    $quantity_per_package = $product->get_meta( '_quantity_per_package' );
    
    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ( $quantity_per_package ) ) {
        $product_attributes[ 'quantity_per_package' ] = array(
            'label' => __('Quantity per Package', 'woocommerce '),
            'value' => $quantity_per_package,
        );
    }
    
    return $product_attributes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'filter_woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 10, 2 );
```